# Make id appear when button is pressed

Tags: php

```
<div class="colx2-left align-center">
                        <?php echo Form::button('create-ncn', 'Create NCN', array('class' => 'small-button', 'id' => 'create-ncn', 'type' => 'button', 'value' => 'create-ncn')) ?>
                    </div>
```

When I press the button above I populate a different form to the one I'm currently on

```
    public function action_create_yimyan()
{
    $this->template = NULL;
    $this->auto_render = FALSE;

    $id = $this->request->param('id');
    $comp = ORM::factory('Comp', $id);
    $comp->ncn_id = $ncn->id;

    $ncn = ORM::factory('NCN');
    $ncn->user_id = Auth::instance()->get_user()->id;
    $ncn->actionee_id = NULL;
    $ncn->ncn_problem_type_id = 6;
    $ncn->status_id = Status::lookup('In Progress', 'ncn');
    $ncn->department_id = Auth::instance()->get_user()->department_id;
    $ncn->title = $comp->description;
    $ncn->customer = $comp->customer;
    $ncn->dt_logged = time();
    $ncn->save();   
}
```

I want to echo the id of ncn_id which is a field in the "Comp" table beside the button, which should appear when I press the button Create NCN.

The ncn_id field in the Comp table does not log

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot dynamically alter a page once it's already loaded. You can use JQuery to print the id number once the button is pressed. Simply set a  placeholder and use the jQuery text() function.
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_text.asp

You can watch for button clicks with the JQuery click() function.
http://api.jquery.com/click/